# Android - System doesn't recognize my theme as dark mode

Tags: android, themes, darkmode

I have two themes. One is:

```
<style name="ThemeDay" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Other one is:

```
<style name="ThemeNight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

I apply themes in every activity like this before `super.onCreate()`

```
if(GenelUtil.getNightMode()){
    setTheme(R.style.ThemeNight);
}else{
    setTheme(R.style.ThemeDay);
}
```

Theme is applied. But system doesnt behave like selected theme.

For example when system is light mode and app is dark mode, Navigation bar is still white, dialogs are still white etc..

But when I open instagram and switch to dark mode, system also behave like its in dark mode.

What do I do wrong here? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DayNight` theme is picking automatically dark or light params/colors basing on system settings (by default) or set/forced by you (e.g. using `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()`)

when you have light theme in your system and you will use `DayNight` theme for your app then still not overriden colors will be same as in "light" theme

Comment: Yes. That's my problem. How can I fix that or override correct colors?

Comment: use only `DayNight` theme and override some colors according to currently set theme (system depend or forced by you). place your values (e.g. colors) inside `values` folder for light and inside `values-night` for night (e.g. two separated `colors.xml` files with proper colors per day/nigt theming)

Comment: your `GenelUtil.getNightMode()` should be `AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode()`, I bet your current aproach just toggle some `boolean` inside app, maybe store in `SharedPreferences`, but still isn't informing `AppCompatDelegate` that you have set "dark" theme

Comment: Yes I store boolean inside sharedprefs. But `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()` worked. Thank you